# Can I put a dependency in both dev and peer dependencies?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, package.json

I am writing a library using vue. Thus I would like to put vue as a peer dependency.

However, nowadays some package managers (pnpm for instance) do not install peer dependency by default when running their `install` command.

Note that this peer dependency is also required to build the package...

Can I put it in both peer and dev dependency ?